# An application of Ito-Doob differential formula

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I want to apply the following formula

$$dV(t,w(t)) = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}V(t,w(t)) + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}V(t,w(t))\right)dt  + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}V(t,w(t))dw(t). $$

to find the differentials of the following functions:

1. $V(t,w(t)) = \sin(w(t)) $
2. $V(t,w(t)) = \exp(t^2-2w^2(t))$

In both cases, $w(t)$ is a Wiener process.

I am a little bit confused because I have derivatives with respect to $x$ in the formula and the functions I'm given has no $x$'s in them.  The examples if the book starts with $V(t,x)$. Then to find for example $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}V(t,w(t))$, I evaluate the partial derivative of $V$ wrt $X$ at $w(t)$.

I would like some help in starting off.

Comment: The functions you are interested in should be defined as $V:(t,x) \mapsto \sin(x) $ and $V:(t,x) \mapsto \exp(t^2-2x^2)$, respectively.

Comment: Thanks. I can now handle the problem then.

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $